# r2dbc Postgres: binary numeric encoding

Tags: postgresql, r2dbc

I'm looing at the [NumericDecodeUtils.java](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/blob/main/src/main/java/io/r2dbc/postgresql/codec/NumericDecodeUtils.java) class and see it can **decode** a numeric type into BigDecimal. I tried to find a place in the repository which, instead, **encodes** a BigDecimal value into byte array (using binary format). But it looks like there is only a text implementation of it.

Does r2dbc Postgres driver have binary numeric encoding implemented?